# (OSError) Exception Handles (ConnectionRefusedError) Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-except

I'm Trying To Catch Errors In Socket Connection With Python. I Need To Work With Two Different Types Of Errors **[ ConnectionRefusedError, OSError ]**. I Want To Perform A Different Action For Each Error, So I Did It With (try except) Statement, And When The Code Is Like The Shown Below *[Which (OSError) Exception Is Written First]*, Only The First Exception *[Which Is (OSError)]* Is Raised Even The Error Is (ConnectionRefusedError)
Code :

```
for ip in ips:
    sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try :
        sock.connect((ip,12345))
        print("Up.")
        up.append(ip)
        sock.close()
    except OSError:
        print("Down.")
        raise
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print("Up.")
        up.append(ip)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

> - Output : Down.
> - Raised Error : ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

So The [OSError] Exception which has The `raise` Statement Raised [ConnectionRefusedError] (Which Is The Next Exception Statement !).

. But When I Swap The Exceptions And Write (ConnectionRefusedError) First, It Works Fine:

```
for ip in ips:
    sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try :
        sock.connect((ip,port))
        print("Up.")
        sock.close()
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print("Up.")
        up.append(ip)
    except OSError:
        print("Down.")
        raise
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

So, Why OSError Exception Handles ConnectionRefusedError In The First Case ?
And Is There A Way To Write OSError Exception First And It Works Immediately ?

Comment: You're not supposed to capitalize every word in English. It's supposed to look like this. It's Not Supposed To Look Like This.

Comment: I Like Writing In This Way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConnectionRefusedError` inherits from `OSError`, so an `except` clause that accepts an `OSError` can match a `ConnectionRefusedError` just fine; in particular, given that `except` clauses are tested in the order in which they are written, if the `OSError` clause is written first, it will match the `ConnectionRefusedError` exception always.

There's no way around this<sup>1</sup>, so as a general rule you want to always write more specific exception handlers before the more generic ones.

---

1. To "fix" this in the general case, the interpreter would have to do a topological sort of the clauses based on inheritance relations for the exception clauses, possibly splitting clauses that specify multiple exceptions, and, given the dynamic nature of the language, do this at runtime, slowing down exceptions for a feature that rarely matters.